# Detect if UIImage is preloaded?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am working on an image viewer application.   I noticed some lag when scrolling and discovered this code to solve the problem:

https://gist.github.com/steipete/1144242

Basically, it just draws the UIImage, to preload/cache it, making the scrolling nice and smooth.

Is there anyway to detect whether a given UIImage is preloaded?

Comment: No but you could create a mutable dictionary and save prerendered images here by name, to keep track of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked at WWDC, there isn't a way to tell.  So I used associated objects attached to my UIImage to track whether it was preloaded or not.